# Printing some medical receipt from django

Tags: python, django

So, i'm working in a Django Project for a Doctor, in which i need to print the medical receipt based on the values inserted into a ModelForm through a UpdateView, there are two conflicts i am facing.

1. I would like that the success_url to redirect me to the same page, something like hitting the 'Save' or 'Submit' button from the form and not sending me to other page just stay in the same.
2. I would like to know how can i create a pdf to be printed but based on the values inserted in that updateview, i've seen some tutorials in the internet but they just render some random text into a html template and use xhtml2pdf to create it to PDF and showing the content using a generic View, but i don't know what path to take so i can use those specific values to create a pdf.

As you can see in my html i have a button with an anchor tag that holds 'Imprimir', so what i mean with all this is entering the update view, filling all the required fields, saving the content and redirecting me to the same page with the content saved, so that then i could hit the 'Imprimir' button, creating a PDF with this particular content and printing it.

Hope you could understand what i am talking about.

## HTML

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load staticfiles%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'appointments/css/appointment_update.css'%}">
    <div class="Form">
        <form method="POST">
            <h3 id="Consult">Informacion de la consulta</h3>
            <h3 id="Patient">Signos Vitales</h3>
            <h3 id="Exams">Estudios:</h3>
            <h3 id="System">Examinacion por Sistema</h3>
            <h3 id="Physical">Examinacion Fisica</h3>
            <h3 id="Diagnose">Diagnostico y Tratamiento</h3>
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input align="center" type="submit" value="Finalizar Consulta">
            <button><a href="">Imprimir</a></button>
        </form>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```

## Models

```
class Consults(models.Model):
    #General Consult Info
    Paciente = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Paciente')
    Fecha = models.DateField()
    Motivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    Padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    #Main Patient Info
    Presion = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    Temperatura = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    Peso = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    Talla = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    #Any Exams done before
    Estudios = models.ImageField(upload_to='studies',blank=True)
    #Interrogatory by System
    Digestivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Endocrino = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Renal = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Linfativo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Respiratorio = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Physical Exploration
    Cabeza = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Torax = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Diagnose
    CIE_10 = models.ForeignKey(CIE_10,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True)
    Detalle_de_Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Procedimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Analisis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Treatment
    Medicamento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Uso = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Dosis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Acciones = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
```

## Views

```
class AppointmentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Consults
    form_class = ConsultForm
    template_name = 'appointments_update.html'
    success_url = '/appointments/appointmentlist'
```

## Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',AppointmentIndexView.as_view(),name='appointmentindex'),
    path('AddConsult',AddAppointmentView.as_view(),name='addappointment'),
    path('appointmentslist/',AppointmentListView.as_view(),name='appointmentlist'),
    path('<int:pk>',AddAppointmentDetailView.as_view(),name='appointmentdetail'),
    path('update/<int:pk>',AppointmentUpdateView.as_view(),name='appointmentupdate'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',AppointmentDeleteView.as_view(),name='appointmentdelete'),
]
```

Comment: Take a look at request types, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc. You can modify your data in the same page with the help of them.

Comment: Oh, i am able to save my data, what i was thinking about was like changing the success_url from the update view to the one that holds my specific updateview, but as you know, everytime i click the object to update it, my url holds an ID at the end, what i don't is how to insert a url that recognizes that specific id, so it would send me to the same page, like simulating a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask question #2 in another post.

For #1, if I understand you correctly, you'd like to redirect the user to the same page. If so, you can override `get_success_url` to redirect to your same path.

```
class AppointmentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("appointmentupdate", kwargs=self.kwargs)
```

Or

```
class AppointmentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return request.path
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @schillingt this was everything i was looking for, and yes i will ask the other question in another post, thanks again!